# Starting a workflow with Javascript errors somtimes

Tags: 2013, workflow, javascript

I'm using the following code to start a workflow from the javascript on an edit form:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var wfServiceManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);
var subscription = wfServiceManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().getSubscription(_workflowId);

context.load(subscription);

... and then on with the async query
```

The problem is with the `wfServiceManger.getWorkflowSubscriptionService()` part. Sometimes the wfServiceManager is created with a context object in it and other times it isn't. I get the following error when there is no contextobject in the workflowServicesManager:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.get_context is not a function
    at SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService
```

I can't see any reason why one time it would return a properly formmed WorkflowServicesManager and other times not.

I'm finding some other places where people get the `this.get_context()` is not a function. Those seem to revolve around loading of required js files. I'm loading:

- core.js
- sp.js
- sp.runtime.js
- sp.ui.dialog.js
- sp.workflowservices.js

And they all seem to be loaded and available (as best I can tell from the debugger).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we had three different problems.

In some of our javascript code we had **"Use strict";** not sure, but that seems to have cause some problems somewhere in the one of the sharepoint javascript files. So we removed it.

We had multiple copies of **sp.js** loading with `SP.SOD.loadMultiple()` in a couple of different js files. We removed that and changed it to `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init, 'SP.js')`.

But removing the loadMultiple meant that **sp.workflows.js** was loading before sp.js, only in IE and not Chrome. So we moved the load of that into the `init` function called when sp.js loads.